# Can you be a Magic Technomancer?

Tags: shadowrun-sr5

During character creation, one of my players realized he could do the following:

- He took a B priority on Metatype, to be a Human with 7 points of Special Attributes.
- He split his points as 1 Edge, and 6 Resonance.
- He then took an A priority on Magic or Resonance, to have Magic 6.

That's when we realized that we couldn't find anywhere a mention of the usual "you can't have Magic and Resonance, impossible, nada".

Did we miss something? Is it written somewhere that we haven't found, or are you supposed to know it from previous editions?

Comment: From previous editions I know for a fact that you can't and I'm actively looking for a reference in the book that specifically says why you cant.

Comment: The rules should definitely have explained this a lot better. Those points for "Special Attributes" will almost always go only to Edge. The only situation where they don't is if you take enough priority in Magic/Resonance to get the attribute, but not enough to max it out, and for some reason you take a high prio on metatype to boost it further. I can only really see a Troll (with +5 on special attributes between prio A and B) do this.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can't. Page 52, very last sentence of the Resonance attribute:

> Non-technomancers have a zero rating for Resonance.

To be a technomancer you must put at least C in the *Magic or Resonance* column. Yes this means that if you put A in Magic or Resonance and B in your Metatype and you're a Human you'll have 7 points to spend on mostly Edge and if you don't spend it it's lost. This is by design.

Also page 63

> A player who wishes to play a technomancer must select an option on the Priority Table (p. 65) that gives the character a Resonance attribute.

Meaning you can't get a Resonance attribute to put points in unless you put C and above in the Magic or Resonance column.

Comment: Great! I highly suspected you can't be both, but was worried by the book not saying it. I wish it would have been said more clearly though, but that works.

Comment: Definitely. They clarified some things but left other details in the fog for some reason..maybe assuming people would know from previous editions.

Comment: Yeah, it was made very clear in SR4, they should have done the same for SR5.

Comment: Additionally Run Faster States that you lose your Resonance completely, when being infected with MMVV (It gives you a magic attrbute of 1) as its not compatible.